# joomla is not finding my model

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

for some reason I can not load my model anywhere. not in my controller, not in my view. here is my code

```
<?php
/**
* Joomla! 1.5 component ad_maker
*
* @version $Id: view.html.php 2011-06-16 12:55:02 svn $
* @author
* @package Joomla
* @subpackage ad_maker
* @license GNU/GPL
*
* makes ads
*
* This component file was created using the Joomla Component Creator by Not Web Design
* http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla_component_creator/
*
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Import Joomla! libraries
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');
class Ad_makerViewDefault extends JView {
    function display($tpl = null) {
      
      $model =& $this->getModel('Ad_maker');
      $model->get('AdList');
      
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
?>
```

My model is located at

## com_ad_maker/models/ad_maker.php

```
<?php
/**
* Joomla! 1.5 component ad_maker
*
* @version $Id: ad_maker.php 2011-06-16 12:55:02 svn $
* @author
* @package Joomla
* @subpackage ad_maker
* @license GNU/GPL
*
* makes ads
*
* This component file was created using the Joomla Component Creator by Not Web Design
* http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla_component_creator/
*
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Import Joomla! libraries
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller' );
jimport('joomla.database.table');

class Ad_makerModelAd_maker extends JModel {
   
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }
   
   public function getTest()
   {
      echo "this is a test";   
   }
   
   public function store()
   {
      $post = $this->_state->get('request');
      
      $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
      
      $url = "images/ads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      $durl =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/ads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];   
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$durl);
      
      $query = "INSERT INTO #__ad_maker (ad_name, image_url, tags) VALUES ('$post[ad_name]', '$url', '$post[tags]')";       
      $db->setQuery($query);
      $result = $db->query();
   }
   
   public function getAdList()
   {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM #__ad_maker";
      $db->setQuery($query);
      $result = $db->query();
      
      return $result;   
   }
   
   public function deleteAd($id)
   {
      $query = "DELETE * FROM #__ad_maker WHERE id = $id";
      $db->setQuery($query);
      $result = $db->query();      
   }
}
?>
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/website/public_html/administrator/components/com_ad_maker/views/default/view.html.php on line 26
```

here is my controller

## com_ad_maker/controller.php

```
<?php
/**
* Joomla! 1.5 component ad_maker
*
* @version $Id: controller.php 2011-06-16 12:55:02 svn $
* @author
* @package Joomla
* @subpackage ad_maker
* @license GNU/GPL
*
* makes ads
*
* This component file was created using the Joomla Component Creator by Not Web Design
* http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla_component_creator/
*
*/

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );
require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers'.DS.'helper.php' );

/**
* ad_maker Controller
*
* @package Joomla
* @subpackage ad_maker
*/
class Ad_makerController extends JController {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @access private
     * @subpackage ad_maker
     */
    function __construct() {
        //Get View
        if(JRequest::getCmd('view') == '') {
            JRequest::setVar('view', 'default');
         
         JRequest::setVar('view', 'default');
        }

        $this->item_type = 'Default';
        parent::__construct();
    }
   
   function add()
   {
      $post   = JRequest::get('post');
      $model =& $this->getModel('Ad_maker');
      
      $model->setState('request', $post);      
      $model->store();      
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of your view is `default`, so Joomla will attempt to load the model named `default` from your component's `models` directory. Change `com_ad_maker/models/ad_maker.php` to `com_ad_maker/models/default.php` and change `class Ad_makerModelAd_maker extends JModel` to `class Ad_makerModelDefault extends JModel` and it should work.

Comment: It works for the add() function, but not within the contstruct function . If my view and model have to be a certain name, then why do I have to put the name of the model within the getModel('name') parameter ?

Comment: You do not have to use `$this->getModel('Ad_maker');` in your view.html.php file, only in the controller.php one. In view.html.php, you can do `$ad_list = $this->get('AdList');` and then `$this->assign('AdList', $ad_list);` to use the results from getAdList() in your default.php file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it helped put me back on track around a mental block _late_ last night. Everything else I found missed that is was the view or was just plain bad (e.g. just include() the PHP file for the model in everything!)